# error: expression must have pointer-to-object type, with matrices

Tags: c++, cuda

Here is the code:

```
__global__
void matrixSumKernelB(float **a, float **b, float **c, int n) {
    // Sums each element per thread
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if (i < n * n) {
        int l = i / n;                  // Line
        int c = (l == 0) ? i : (n - i); // Column
        a[l][c] = b[l][c] + c[l][c];
    }
}
```

The compiler says that the error is in this line:

```
a[l][c] = b[l][c] + c[l][c];
```

As you can see,  I'm trying to sum two matrices(b and c) and store the result in a third matrix(a), but i'm getting this annoying error when I try to compile.

I've already searched for this in other questions, but in most of them, the problem is that they passed an 1d array and were trying to access them as an 2d array, which is not my case. Probably is something stupid I haven't noticed yet, but i'm having a hard time here. Any clues?

PS: This is an exercise from [Programming Massively Parallel Processors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124159923), chapter 3

Comment: Do you see anything weird in this expression: `c[l][c]`?

Comment: I recommend you actually read your code. This place isn't a trivial mistake spotting service, please don't treat it like one.

Comment: If you had used descriptive variable names instead of "nonsense with a comment", this would never have happened.

Comment: You are right. The funny thing is, i've read it many times and hadn't found anything weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int c = (l == 0) ? i : (n - i); // Column
```

After this, `c` the local variable hides `c` the function parameter. This also applies in this subexpression: `c[l][c]`.

Solution: rename the local variable `c` to something else. `col` or `column` comes to mind, which would make the comment on the declaration redundant. Likewise, `line` (or even better, `row`) would be a better name for `l`.